# How to imitate AJAX-like behavior in Rails app, but initiate request from the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app in which I have created a series of filters for the user to click (checkboxes). When the user clicks them, I want to initiate a request to a database and update the data displayed.

I have currently implemented this with client-side Javascript. I listen for the change in the filters, and initiate an AJAX request to the server. When the data comes back, I just update the HTML directly using JS.

However, I would now like the request to come from the Rails app on the server, so that I can ensure that only authorized requests are made to the database.

How can I simulate this same behavior: listening to the change-events on the UI-widgets; making a request; and updating the page in-place, while initiating the request from the server?

Comment: Initiating what request? Authorized by whom/what? The question does not make sense as in both cases the client is initiating the action. While you can use WebSockets to create a duplexed (two-way) connection where the server can push data to the client this is usually used for things like chatrooms, stock tickers and "live" updates where the server is notifying the client of an something that happened on the server.

Comment: I meant that I'd like the request to be initiated on the server. I'd like the server to request the data, and update a partial or something to display the data to the user.

Comment: Still does not make sense since your server is the only one making requests to the db.

Comment: There are three things: my Rails app on a server, a completely separate DB not directly tied to my app, and the client machine. Currently, I make an AJAX request to the DB from the client machine with Javascript. I'd like to move this request to by initiated from the Rails app on the server. I'm not sure why this doesn't make sense, but clearly I'm not explaining something well.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to use your Rails server as a proxy to connect to another server you can use the built in [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) library or gems like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) which have additional features.

This is commonly done when you're calling an external API.

You can use models in rails which are not tied to ActiveRecord by using [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html).

```
# note that this should not inherit from
# ActiveRecord::Base
class ApplicationModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'example.com/api'
end

class Thing < ApplicationModel

  def self.find(id)
    self.new( get("/2.2/things/"+ id, options) )
  end

  def self.all(*options)
    # fetches
    response = get("/2.2/things", options)
    response.map do |r|
      self.new(r)
    end
  end
end
```

This example uses HTTParty to connect to fictional API.

Comment: Thanks. How about the other part of the behavior: whenever the user updates the value of a filter in the UI, I make the request again, without reloading the page. Is that possible?